# What is the proper naming of a shared header file

Tags: c++

I work on a C++ project with multiple files. I want 2 of these files to have some shared (global, between these 2 variables). Thus, I want to declare these variables inside a header file that will be included to both of these files.

The only purpose of this header file will be this. What would be a proper non-confusing name?

I thought something like `filename1_filename2_shared.h` but I would like to know what is the most common name for something like this.

Comment: The most common approach is to avoid shared state.

Comment: Your code should work regardless of who uses it, having the filenames in any identifier is just leaking implementation.

Comment: Why is it shared in the first place? What is it that is shared? As GManNikG says, naming something after the files that uses it seems a pretty poor plan.

Comment: Well, consider the following: You have a mainwindow and a preferences dialog (which are classes with separate cpp and h files each). Preferences can change values that affect mainwindow. Global variables are more efficient than sending signals with emit, no?

Comment: @user9379: Signals are superior. They're cleaner, easier to maintain, and easier to reason about, scalable, etc... Globals are bad design.

Comment: @GManNickG thanks for the information. Is there any other way even superior to signals?

Comment: @user9379: I'm not sure. I'm not much of a UI guy. Just don't base your designs around what you think might or might not be "efficient". Efficiency goes beyond what the computer executes, it needs to actually help you get work done too. I bet if you implemented both a global variables variant and a signals variant, I could inject a per-signal sleep of at least 50 milliseconds to the signal implementation and you would not notice the performance difference. Fast enough is the best kind of fast. ;)

Comment: @yzt I clearly said "I want to *declare* these variables inside a header file", and ofcourse I meant using `extern`, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to name your file with the purpose of those variables. For example if your variables describe how the process was started, you can name the file `ProcessStartupInfo.H`.

You cannot declare global variables in the header. They should be declared in one of your source files. If you have in file1:

```
int myVar1;
int myVar2;
```

Then in your file2 you should put:

```
extern    int myVar1;
extern    int myVar2;
```

or, as another approach you can put into your header:

```
extern    int myVar1;
extern    int myVar2;
```

and include this header either into the second file or into both files.

Comment: Okay, that is expected, but what if the variables where the shared variables need to be do unrelated jobs (E.g. main and preferences window so as the preferences window to update the changed values for the main window)

Comment: Ok, I marked you as correct because I understand that my question cannot be answered, or there isn't a "default" way to do such a thing. I knew how to use shared/global variables between cpp files, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can select some very general name like `EnvironmentInfo.H` or `WindowManagementInfo.H`

Comment: You can DECLARE global vars in a header file just fine -- that is what your third block does.  You shoudn't DEFINE globabl vars in a header, because that leads to multiple definitions if you include the header in mltiple source files.  They need to be DEFINED in exactly one source file.